# Live video broadcasting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, html5-video

I am going to develop a chat based application for mobile which allows video chat. I am using HTML5, javascript and PhoneGap. Using phoneGap, I am able to access mobile camera, capture a video, save the video and upload it in server. I have done it for android. But I need live broadcasting of the video. Is there any solution of that?
Note: It is not any android native app.

Comment: I found out some links suggesting it's impossible with PhoneGap stackoverflow.com/questions/11573920/live-video-broadcasting https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/kaK-KtqPnZc I'm also trying same kind of application, so please comment if you find anything useful. Or try using Sencha, Titanium or Rho mobile.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what facility you're currently using for the video capture. AFAIK, current WebView doesn't yet support WebRTC which is the w3 standard that will soon enable you to access the video frames in your HTML5 code. So I'm assuming you're using PhoneGap's `navigator.device.capture.captureVideo` facility.

On Android, `captureVideo` creates 3gp files. The problem with 3gp is that they cannot be streamed or played while capturing: the MOOV atom of the file is required for parsing the video frames in it, and it is written only after all frames in the file have been encoded. So you must stop the recording before you can make any use of the file.

Your best shot in HTML5 is to implement a loop that captures a short clip (3-5 seconds?) of video, then sends it to a server while the next chunk is being captured. The server will need to concatenate the clips to a single file that can be broadcast with a streaming server. This will add several seconds to the latency of the broadcast, and you are quite likely to suffer from lost frames at the point in the gap between two separate chunk captures. That might be sufficient for some use cases (security cameras, for example).

If your application is such that you cannot afford to lose frames, I see no other option but to implement the video capture and streaming in Java, as a PhoneGap Plugin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Now what I am trying to do is that, I am using phonegap, but whenever user tries video calling, I am transferring the control to android native functions. I am capturing the video using Android Mediarecorder by which I have full control over the recording. But I am only able to save the video in local file. I need to stream it. Is there any way to do it. I have found one solution [Here](http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system). But I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Any solution that uses 3GP or MP4 as its file format will be a problem for live streaming, as these files cannot be played before they are finalized (the MOOV atom needs to be completed with frame offsets information). I've seen one project that works by converting the video to FLV, a file format that can be live-streamed: http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/ - but note that it (1) is GPL and (2) uses JNI

Answer (score 1):

See Spydroid http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

It uses the solution with the special FileDescriptor you found. Basically they let the video encoder write a .mp4 with H.264 to the special file descriptor that calls your code on write. Then they strip off the MP4 header and turn the H.264 NALUs into RTP packets.